# Android Yammer authentication issue

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, yammer

Can't authenticate with Yammer.
I've tried to use socialauth library but without any success.
public void onError(SocialAuthError socialAuthError) 
Error log:
org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthConfigurationException: Problem in getting Access Token. Application key or Secret key may be wrong.The server running the application should be same that was registered to get the keys.
Could not connect using SocialAuth
I've checked the keys again and both consumer_key and consumer_secret are right.
Even got the issue registered, but seems the project is not supported anymore.

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/issues/detail?id=385&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified

With my own authentication I could get an access token, but could not make any REST-API call. Just getting an error "Unauthorized" (401) all the time.
HTTP params are fine according to docs, got all the cookies, but can't use REST-API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The problem was in wrong headers placement. I've been setting headers to response handler for loopj async http client, with the method handler.setRequestHeaders(...);, but the right way is to add headers to client - client.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);